# C++ Const Char data size Confusion

Tags: c++, size

I'm working on a challenge to build a C++ text adventure game that will fit on a 1.44MB floppy disk.
I'm using ASCII art for chapter images.
Each ASCII art image is made out of 40 "cout" lines with 78 character in the line to form the image.

For example:

`cout << "#############################################################################" << endl;`

From my understanding, "cout" defines the contents as a "const char".

After some research I understand a char data type is 1 byte but I could not find a reliable answer to the size of a "const char".

If I'm understanding the data size right, the maths for one ASCII image should be 78(char)*40(lines) to get 3120 bytes or 3.12KB.

I'm unsure whether or not the characters themselves effects the size and if the addition of "const" increase the data size.

Comment: `const char` size is the same as just `char`

Comment: Your calculation is correct. There is 3120 bytes of character data in one screen.

Comment: ""cout" defines the contents as a "const char"" - `cout` doesn't *define* anything - it just outputs what it is given.

Comment: Side note: This would compress amazingly well with RLE compression :)

Comment: Also ask yourself the question how many "characters" do you want to be able to show on your screen.  If it is mostly only 16 different characters to draw a level you can encode for 2 characters per byte.  And then say `0000` = `#` and `0001` = `@` and even use less memory.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Haha that too! ;) I must say this challenge does bring back memories about memory

Comment: FYI, if there are no format instructions, you can define the text as "static const char text[]" with "\n" where you need `endl`, then use `std::cout.write()` to output the text.  Reduces your `cout` lines to one.  The compiler knows the length at compile time, so you can use `sizeof(text)`, or `sizeof(text) - 1` if you don't like outputting nul characters.

Comment: *'From my understanding, "cout" defines the contents as a "const char".'* That does not make any sense. `cout` is an object, specifically a stream which writes to the standard output. It does not define anything. Hard to know what the real issue is here.

Comment: The literal string `"###...###"` is a constant array of characters, and includes the string null-terminator. And as other arrays it decays to a pointer to its first element, which then have the type `const char*`.

Comment: FYI, `cout << "###...###" << endl;` can be greatly simplified using the [`std::setw()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [`std::setfill()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) stream manipulators, eg: `cout << setw(78) << setfill('#') << '\n';` ([demo](https://ideone.com/Ip0MtG)). That will help you reduce your memory usage, while still giving you the same output.

Comment: @Shadow7711 The size of  "const char" is equal exactly to 11.:) You can check that yourself as std::cout << sizeof(  "const char" );

Answer (score 2):

> From my understanding, "cout" defines the contents as a "const char".

It does not. `std::cout` is an `std::ostream` for which there are a number of `operator<<` overloads of which one is:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const char* s);
```

This merely reads the characters pointed at by `s` until a null terminator (`\0`) is encountered and outputs them to the device.

> I understand a char data type is 1 byte but I could not find a reliable answer to the size of a "const char"

`const`ness doesn't affect the size. The size of a `const char` is the same as the size of a non-`const` `char` - and the size is defined to be 1. You can print the result of `sizeof(char)` and `sizeof(const char)` to verify.

> 3120 bytes or 3.12KB

78*40 equals 3120, that's correct, but 3120 bytes is not 3.12 KB. `KB` is the old way of writing `KiB`, that is, kilobinary. 3120 is 3.046875 KiB or 3.12 kB.